# String of point to PointCollection

Tags: c#, string, list, point

If I have a [`PointCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.pointcollection%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

```
var points = new PointCollection();
points.Add(new Point(0, 0));
points.Add(new Point(10, 10));
points.Add(new Point(20, 20));
points.Add(new Point(30, 30));
```

I can get the equivalent `string` using:

```
string str = points.ToString();
```

And now `str` is:

> 0,0 10,10 20,20 30,30

How can I get the reverse process?

Comment: reverse process as in taking a string and converting it to a list of points?

Comment: returns "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Drawing.Point]" for me

Comment: Also, if ^ is true then how will the string be inputted?

Comment: _"And now str is:

    0;0 10;10 20;20 30;30
"_ No, it's System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Drawing.Point]

Comment: Can we see the `Point` and `List<Point>` classes, please?

Comment: @jonnyGold http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.point.aspx

Comment: @Nick: I don't have WPF here, have you tested [my code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11159408/284240)? PointCollection implements `IEnumerable<Point>`, so you should be able to use `String reverse = string.Join(" ", points.Reverse().Select(p => p.X + ";" + p.Y));`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [`PointCollection.Parse` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.pointcollection.parse.aspx):

```
PointCollection points = PointCollection.Parse(str);
```

Answer (score 5):

Something like this?

```
var points = str.Split(' ').Select(x => 
{
    var c = x.Split(';');
    return new Point(int.Parse(c[0]), int.Parse(c[1]));
}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

*"And now str is:*

```
0;0 10;10 20;20 30;30
```

"_ No, it's `System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.Drawing.Point]` instead.

If you want to output the points as `String`, separate the X/Y values with semicolon and the points with semi-colon, you have to do it yourself.

For example:

```
String forward = string.Join(" ", points.Select(p => p.X + ";" + p.Y));
points.Reverse();  // reverse the order of the list
String backward = string.Join(" ", points.Select(p => p.X + ";" + p.Y));
```

[`List(Of T).Reverse` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5c6526tb.aspx)

**Edit**: So actually you're not using a `List<Point>` but a WPF [`PointCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.pointcollection%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). I neither have experiences with it nor can i test it. But since it implements `IEnumerable<Point>` you should be able to do:

```
String backward = string.Join(" ", points.Reverse().Select(p => p.X + ";" + p.Y));
```

Comment: I have the string and I want the PointCollection, +1 for your help

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 string strpoints = "0;0 10;10 20;20 30;30";
            var strpointarray = strpoints.Split(' ');
            var points = new List<Point>();
            foreach (var item in strpointarray)
            {
                var newitem= item.Split(';');
                points.Add(new Point(int.Parse(newitem[0]),int.Parse(newitem[1])));
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a function `toPoint` which takes two arguments and converts them to numbers, passes it to new Point and returns that...

Here is a link with some built in String -> Number methods http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397679.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to define conversion operators. In conversion operators u need to write the code "ie" provided. 
Here are links for Conversion Operatores(Explicit and implict)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/z5z9kes2%28v=vs.80%29
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/xhbhezf4%28v=vs.80%29